# Using regular expression for rm and ls

Tags: grep, regular-expression, ls, rm, xargs

**QUESTION:**

What is happening here and how do I fix it?

**PROBLEM:**

When I do:

```
$ls | grep -P "file[1-9]{3}.txt|file[1-9]{2}.txt"
```

I get:

```
file11.txt
file12.txt
file13.txt
file14.txt
file15.txt
file16.txt
file17.txt
file18.txt
file19.txt
file21.txt
file22.txt
file23.txt
file24.txt
file25.txt
file26.txt
file27.txt
file28.txt
file29.txt
etc.
```

But when I do:

```
$ls | grep -P "file[1-9]{3}.txt|file[1-9]{2}.txt" | xargs -d"\n" rm
```

I get:

```
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile11.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile12.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile13.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile14.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile15.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile16.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile17.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile18.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile19.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile21.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile22.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile23.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile24.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile25.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile26.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile27.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile28.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile29.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile31.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile32.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile33.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile34.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile35.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile36.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile37.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile38.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile39.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile41.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile42.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile43.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile44.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile45.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile46.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile47.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile48.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile49.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile51.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile52.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile53.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile54.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile55.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile56.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile57.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile58.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile59.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile61.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile62.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile63.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile64.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile65.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile66.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile67.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile68.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile69.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile71.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile72.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile73.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile74.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile75.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile76.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile77.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile78.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile79.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile81.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile82.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile83.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile84.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile85.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile86.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile87.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile88.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile89.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile91.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile92.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile93.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile94.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile95.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile96.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile97.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile98.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[38;5;253mfile99.txt'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
etc.
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

> rm removes all the files that match the regex

Comment: that looks a lot the colorization codes, do you have an alias for grep?

Comment: especially an alias with `--colo[u]r=always`? Or have you set envvar `GREP_COLOR[S]`?

Comment: @Jasen `$alias
alias ls='ls --color=always'
`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 see the above comment, `question` if aliases are defined elsewhere do they not show when running `alias`

Comment: Correct that [`you shouldn’t parse ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440), but to that you need to get ride of the aliases by escaping them like `\ls | \grep ...` as one those ways (assuming no whitespaces or of course `\n`ewline are present in files name)

Comment: @Jasen from `bashrc` ==> `alias ls="ls --color=always"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either `ls` or `grep` is adding colour codes; there’s probably an alias involving `--color=always` somewhere. (Regarding your sub-question, all active aliases are shown when you run `alias`.)

In any case, [you shouldn’t parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440). Use `find` (the GNU variety) instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/file[1-9]{2,3}.txt' -delete
```

(You should also change your alias to use `--color=auto`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked like a charm, but to changing alias is not an option as I have a addon or program or whatever it's called named LS_COLORS from git that colorizes my ls output magnificently

Comment: `ls --color=auto` will still use `LS_COLORS`; the difference with `always` is that `auto` won’t emit colour codes if `ls`’s output isn’t going to a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the same with `rm` only:

```
rm file[1-9][1-9][1-9].txt file[1-9][1-9].txt
```

Comment: Would be worth explaining yours is a shell glob rather than an RE